# Color Code Specific Words/Phrases in a Unix/Linux Terminal Regardless of the Command Used that Prints that Word/Phrase

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, ansi

Is there a way in Unix/Linux to always color-code specific words/phrases no matter what made those words/phrases appear as output on the terminal? I know you can write scripts/programs to print out any colors you want, but I was wondering if it could happen no matter how that word/phrase got printed to the terminal. You can use commands to print and add colors that way too, but is it possible to color code them no matter how they get printed to the terminal?

Comment: This would be a feature of the terminal emulator being used, I think. iTerm has such a feature. Not sure about equivalents in Linux terminal emulators - maybe Konsole has this? Terminator can highlight text if you search for it.

Comment: If you feel like hacking a bit (at least patching & compiling, maybe having to update the patch beforehand), VTE (used by gnome-terminal and many others) has a proof of concept patch at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7771. The rules are hardwired, you have to modify the source to change them, and only plain string match (no regex) is implemented. Other than these convenience issues, if you manage to update the rules and compile and install it, it should work fully reliably.